# What is an reflective tower?

Tags: type-theory, reflection

I've just read in a [discussion about dynamic typing](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/4875#comment-78361)

> Reflective towers is an open problem for statically typed languages.

What are reflective towers?

I think it might be related to reflection, but I'm not sure.

If you create an example, I would prefer Java.

Answer (score 5):

A reflective tower is a model for language extension. It is modeled as an infinite (tower) series of interpreters. Each interpreter is executing a program which is the interpreter one level bellow it with the programmers' program being at level 0.

Each program is a piece of code that performs computation and in that sense a function but it is also a modifiable struct (it is a data-structure).

You can read about it [here](http://www2.parc.com/csl/groups/sda/publications/papers/Mendhekar-Reflect93/for-web.pdf)